# What if the number ten was a single digit in the base 10 number system? How would that work?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, number-systems

I've recently been studying about math, and when learning about decimals. I found myself with this question.

An explanation I got from Quora was:
Arithmetic operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division would have to be adapted to the new system. For example, the sum of two numbers that would currently result in 20, in the new system would result in 10-10.

But, I want to know if there are more examples where 10 as a unique digit would make harder the operations. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think adding a 10 digit to a base 10 system will do anything interesting because 10 is the only thing it will represent.  5+5 = A.  A+A = 20.  50 + 50 = 100.  I suppose you could get squirrely if there were things that started with 10.. 50 + 50 = A0?  Since there is no longer a 1 to 1 representation of numbers to how it's written, some things may be writable in two ways.  You wouldn't be able to use it in the middle of things, though.  510 != 5A.

Comment: That would be called the base 11 system. It already has a single digit representing 10

Comment: If you wanted to just be able to use 10s wherever you want, people would have to interpret them.  AA = 110.  A2A2 = 10303.

Comment: I strongly recommend you play with "exploding dots". That's a discussion of "place value" where any integer is allowed in any of the places. https://www.explodingdots.org/

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible to consider base $N$ number representations which don't restrict digits to the range $0 \ldots N-1$. Allowing the digits to range from $0$ to $10$ in a decimal system makes the system ambiguous: writing $A$ for the digit $10$, you can write twenty as either $20$ or $1A$ (not $AA$ as you suggest). It is a moot point whether this makes the arithmetic operations harder: on the one hand, there are more digit-wise operations to think about, but on the other hand you can avoid some carries and borrows: $9 + 1 = A$ with no carry.

If you are interested to know more about this, then Volume 2 of Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming* is a good place to start. One of the fascinating systems that Knuth discusses is *balanced ternary*: base $3$ arithmetic using the digits $-1$, $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The paper "Fast exact summation using small and large superaccumulators" https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05571 provides a real world example how using "exotic" number representations can lead to efficient algorithms for computing with numbers . There the digits are 64-bit signed integers, and the digits "overlap" by having only a $2^{32}$ factor for the base. This way many (as in millions) numbers can be added together digit-by-digit without the need to carry. Right before that would happen, the number is brought to normalized form, and so the carries are amortized over many operations.

Comment: @kaba: thanks for your comment: I was aware that there are practical examples like this but didn't have a reference at my finger tips.

Answer (score 1):

One nice thing about a base system as it is usually configured is that representations of integers are unique. In your nonstandard base ten system, where you have a digit representing ten, let's call it $T$, you no longer have unique representation of integers. For instance, ten could be represented as $T$ or as $10$ ($1$ ten and $0$ ones). Or one hundred could be represented as $T0$ or $9T$ or $100$.